# How do I convert strings into objects in Django or python?

Tags: python, django

has been defined:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'account', 'mobile'）
```

then i define `tem_str = 'UserSerializer'`.
How to convert `tem_str` to a UserSerializer object and get its Meta content in python or django?

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'account', 'mobile'）
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` :

```
instance = eval('UserSerializer()')
instance.Meta.model       # this will access User model
instance.Meta.fields[0]   # this will access first field of your User model
```

But `eval` is [dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) so avoid using it instead you can have a dictionary which would store names of your class in it and you can access them with their names like this:

```
 class_dict = {'UserSerializer': UserSerializer}

 instance = class_dict['UserSerializer']()
 instance.Meta.model
 instance.Meta.fields[0]
```